# joomla file params.ini is unwritable!

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

In Joomla, when I try to change the template,  I get this message:

```
file params.ini is unwritable!
```

How would I fix this problem without having to change the permission to `0777` ?

Comment: Well, you'll have to change the permissions to *something* - 0755 should do the job, though.

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT modify file if you do not have permission to do that.

You have to give write permission to the document owner. You can easily change the permission with this extension, http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/2630, or through CPANEL or SSH.

This extension is great, I use it on most of the sites that I manage. Never had a problem.

If you want the file to remain unwritable you can change the permission back to original state once you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal fix is to use a host (or have your host change your server) so that PHP runs as a CGI script instead of an Apache module. This means that PHP processes can be run as your own user rather than the server default user making the install more secure and giving you a lot more flexibility in writing to files without having to mess around with permissions.